# Why am I getting "createProperty is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, bots

I'm new to Azure and Azure Bot Framework. I was starting my basic bot (generated with Azure itself and with some adjustments to simplify the bot to have a better understanding afterwards), but after `npm start` I got this error:

```
TypeError: userState.createProperty is not a function
```

I've searched on Azure documentation, here and wherever I could, but I didn't find a solution yet. Here is the code that caused the error:

```
const USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY = 'USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY';
/* some code */
this.luisRecognizer = luisRecognizer;
this.userState = userState;
this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);
```

And here is the full error trace:

```
C:\Users\Username\Desktop\botdirectory\dialogs\mainDialog.js:36
        this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);
                                             ^

TypeError: userState.createProperty is not a function
    at new MainDialog (C:\Users\Username\Desktop\botdirectory\dialogs\mainDialog.js:36:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Username\Desktop\botdirectory\index.js:82:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! core-bot@1.0.0 start: `node ./index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-bot@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-09T09_44_40_348Z-debug.log
```

**EDIT:**

To give more context, I was using as reference [this](https://github.com/MatDau/ISISLabHelpDesk/blob/main/dialogs/mainDialog.js) dialog to implement my main dialog, and here there's not `userState.createProperty<PropertyAccessor>`, that's why I didn't know it would be necessary, so I'll give it a try.

About where to find `userState`, here is the code (it's in a different file, the error is in my `mainDialog.js`, `userState` comes from `index.js`):

```
/** all require are omitted **/

const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
const conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);

const { LuisAppId, LuisAPIKey, LuisAPIHostName } = process.env;
const luisConfig = { applicationId: LuisAppId, endpointKey: LuisAPIKey, endpoint: `https://${ LuisAPIHostName }` };

const luisRecognizer = new StreamAdvLuis(luisConfig);

const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);
//My main dialog
const dialog = new MainDialog(luisRecognizer, userState);
//My bot
const bot = new DialogBot(conversationState, userState, dialog);

const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log('\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator');
    console.log('\nTo talk to your bot, open the emulator select "Open Bot"');
});

// Listen for incoming activities and route them to your bot main dialog.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    // Route received a request to adapter for processing
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        // route to bot activity handler.
        await bot.run(turnContext);
    });
});

// Listen for Upgrade requests for Streaming.
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
    // Create an adapter scoped to this WebSocket connection to allow storing session data.
    const streamingAdapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
        appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
        appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
    });
    // Set onTurnError for the BotFrameworkAdapter created for each connection.
    streamingAdapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler;

    streamingAdapter.useWebSocket(req, socket, head, async (context) => {
        // After connecting via WebSocket, run this logic for every request sent over
        // the WebSocket connection.
        await bot.run(context);
    });
});
```

Comment: share `mainDialog.js` file around line 36

Comment: Line 36 of `mainDialog.js` is `this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);`

Comment: @SimonaPentangelo - You haven't shown us where `userState` is coming from. What type of object is it? How is it created? Can you link to any samples you've followed? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDeaney I've updated my question, adding more code and the code reference that I was using. Also didn't now about the @ (my bad), so thanks!

Comment: @SimonaPentangelo - Does it really not throw an error when you declare `const userState` the second time?

Comment: @SimonaPentangelo - Are you still working on this?

Comment: Any update on this by any chance? Running into the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

*The JavaScript exception **"is not a function"** occurs when there was an attempt to call a value from a function, but the value is not actually a function.*

**Please note** that [UserState.CreateProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/userstate?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#createProperty_T__string_) returns [StatePropertyAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/statepropertyaccessor?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) interface. Hence, `this.userProfileAccessor` should be an implementation of `StatePropertyAccessor` and your function call should be like: `userState.createProperty<PropertyAccessor>(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);`

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: @singhh-sdft I've updated my question, anyway I'll try this, I'll give another update here if it works or there'll be other problems while trying this.

Comment: sure. Pls use debugger and share insights incase it does not work